# Wrong max-width for div with absolute position in a smaller div with relative position

Tags: html, css

I have a div element positioned relative with 10px width and height. Inside the div I have div positioned absolutely with max-width 200px and this div contains a long text. The problem is that the inner div is not stretched to 200px but is much more narrow. Is there a way that I can keep the same properties and have the inner div stretched to 200px?

```
<div style="position:relative; width:10px; height:10px; display:inline-block;">
  <div style="position:absolute; max-width:200px; display:block;">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LM3V4/6/

ADDITIONAL INFO: The outer div is kind of icon in a text and the inner div is kind of tooltip next to the icon so I cannot change the size of outer element.

SOLUTION: Ok so what has solved my problem is that you have to wrap the inner element with another div with position: absolute and width set to 200px. http://jsfiddle.net/LM3V4/17/

Comment: You have a typo in the style of the second `div`. It should be `position: absolute;`.

Comment: Yes, also in the first div. It should be position relative. My apologies.

Comment: Of course it's not stretched. How can you fit a 200 ft long bed in a 10 ft long house? Your wrapper div is 10px wide while the inner one is 200px wide. You can set the width of the inner to 200px but it will flow out of the container.

Comment: Yes I fully understand this from html point of view. But is there some workaround?

Comment: Why do you need it like this? If we know what exactly you want to achieve and why there's better chance that we're able to help

Comment: I added some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LM3V4/13/)

```
min-width:200px;
```

you need to change max to min

Comment: Thanks, but not really. If I have only one word inside than it should be stretched based on the word.

Answer (score 0):

So i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, it's been mentioned that you're parent container's width is set to 10px so the max-width of the childs will only ever reach 10px not 200px. I've updated your jsfiddle, moving the max-width to the outer div like -

```
.outer
{
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/LM3V4/15/ , let me know if this is the effect you're looking for or something else. Also you don't need to change the DIVs positioning to achieve this, I left it in as it was.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The outer element is kind of icon in the text and the inner element is kind of tooltip next to the icon so I cannot change the size of outer element.

Comment: Ok, so I think you may need to update your original question so people can get a better understanding of the effect you're after. Sounds like you want an icon (perhaps button) to be coupled with a tooltip that has a max-width. Your first question touches on the way CSS handles absolutely positioned elements dimensions, effectively taking them out of the flow of the layout.